# Linux Mint & LIFEREA rss reader

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

I have the linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon distribution installed on my laptop and I cannot launch the software Liferea from the terminal, although, it will work fine if I launch that using the menu/icon.

Typing the following command:

```
liferea
```

in the terminal I should be able to start the program, but, instead, the following error message comes out:

```
I/O error : Permission denied
I/O error : Permission denied
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/p/.config/liferea/feedlist.opml"

** (liferea:4728): WARNING **: XML error while reading OPML file! Could not import "/home/p/.config/liferea/feedlist.opml"!

** (liferea:4728): ERROR **: Fatal: Feed list import failed! You might want to try to restore
the feed list file /home/p/.config/liferea/feedlist.opml from the backup in /home/p/.config/liferea/feedlist.opml.backup
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

What's the problem?

Why do I get this error message?